# Will android load all the res of a activity into memory when it create?

Tags: android, android-resources, android-memory

I'm just curious and do a test.

just a simple app with one activity A.
there's a button and a ImageView(ivTest) in A and I put a large picture(1024x1024) img.jpg in the drawable.
when the button trigger it calls ivTest.setImageResource(R.drawable.img) and the picture appear of course.

here's the test:

1.launch app, click the button, see the picture, no problem.
now kill the application.

2.delete file: data/app/com.test-1.apk (the test device is root so I can do that), launch app, see error "ClassNotFoundException", it's as expected(the apk files in device is removed).
now re-install application.

3.launch app, delete file: data/app/com.test-1.apk, click the button, and the picture is still shown.HOW?

I'm assuming that android system will load all the res of the activity into memory so that it can still show the picture even if I delete the apk file.
But when I add 10 large pictures(10M each) into res/drawable and launch the activity the memory doesn't go up in Android Monitor.

So confused.  Can anyone explain this?  Thanks in advance.